# If $\widehat{L(f)}=P\hat{f}$ then $\widehat{L(F)}=P\hat{F}$ in a distribution sense, where $P$ is characteristic polynomial?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $P$ be a characteristic polynomial $\sum_{\mid \alpha\mid\leq m}a_\alpha (2\pi i\xi)^\alpha$ corresponding to some differential operator $L=\sum_{\mid\alpha\mid\leq m}a_\alpha\partial^\alpha_x$. Let $f$ be in Schwartz class and let $F$ be a distribution induced by $f$.

I want to know if $\hat{L(f)}=P\hat{f}$ then $\hat{L(F)}=P\hat{F}$ in a distribution sense. First, is it true? While I was studying distribution theory, this ought to be true in order to understand what was going on in the book.

So I was evaluating both distributions in some Schwartz class function $\phi$, but I am not sure how to evaluate $\hat{L(F)}(\phi)$ because of $(-1)^{\mid\alpha\mid}$ factor when we deal with differential operator. So how do I show that $\hat{L(F)}(\phi)=P\hat{F}(\phi)$?

> Context: this comes up in observing that when solving PDE, it suffices
> to find $\hat{F}(\xi)=1/P(\xi)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Differential operators are Fourier multipliers whose symbols are the polynomials corrresponding to replacing $D_\alpha$ by $\xi^\alpha$, so it is definitely true that $\widehat{Lf}=P\hat{f}.$ This naturally extends to making sense in distribution due to how operations on distributions are defined. In particular, if we let $M_\alpha f(x)=(ix)^\alpha f(x)$ and $\tilde{M}_\alpha f(x)=(-ix)^{\alpha}f(x),$ then
\begin{align*}
\langle \widehat{Lf},\varphi\rangle &=\langle Lf,\hat{\varphi}\rangle=\sum a_\alpha\langle \partial_\alpha f, \varphi\rangle=\sum (-1)^{|\alpha|}a_\alpha\langle f, \partial_\alpha\hat{\varphi}\rangle\\
&=\sum (-1)^{|\alpha|}a_\alpha\langle f,\widehat{\tilde{M}_\alpha\varphi}\rangle=\sum (-1)^{|\alpha|}a_\alpha\langle \hat{f},\tilde{M}_\alpha\varphi\rangle\\
&=\sum (-1)^{|\alpha|}a_\alpha\langle \tilde{M}_\alpha\hat{f},\varphi\rangle=\sum\limits a_\alpha\langle M_\alpha \hat{f},\varphi\rangle\\
&=\langle P\hat{f},\varphi\rangle.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! If you don't mind can you please tell me about the idea of introducing $M_a f$ and $\tilde{M}_a f(x)$? We're using multiplication formula twice and in between we have translation of $M_a$ but what's the underlying idea?

Comment: I mostly did it for notational reasons, but the big thing that I used was in equality #4: we can write $\partial_\alpha \hat{\varphi}$ as $\widehat{\tilde{M}_\alpha \varphi}.$ That is, we can translate the former term into the Fourier transform of a multiplication operator, and the multiplication has the $(-1)^{|\alpha|}$ which you had from the distributional derivatives. So, the $-1$'s all cancel out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped

Comment: Awesome, glad it was helpful!